# Is there a real $x$ which is eventually writable from an ordinal parameter $\alpha < \omega_1$, but not from $\omega_1$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, ordinal-numbers

According to Lemma 3.14 in the paper [“Recognizable sets and Woodin cardinals: Computation beyond the constructible universe”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06101), there is a real $x$ in $L$ which is recognizable from some ordinal $\alpha$ that is countable in $L$, but not from $\omega_1$.

But I have the following question: do there exist a countable ordinal $\alpha < \omega_1$ and a real $x$ such that there exists an OTM-program which eventually writes $x$ in the parameter $\alpha$, but there does not exist an OTM-program which eventually writes $x$ in the parameter $\omega_1$?

Here “eventually writes $x$” implies that an infinite binary sequence written in an initial segment of length $\omega$ of the output tape stabilizes, and this stable value is equal to $x$. Additionally, “in the parameter $\alpha$” implies that all machines start a computation with zeroes written on all cells of all tapes, except that the symbol $1$ is written on an $\alpha$-th cell of the input tape.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, for each ordinal $\alpha$ the set of reals eventually writeable in parameter $\alpha$ is countable in $L$. So you just need to show that there are $L$-uncountably-many reals which are eventually writeable in some ordinal parameter.

Comment: Noah, why don't you post that as an answer? Namely, there are only countably many reals eventually writable from parameter $\omega_1$, but for every countable ordinal $\alpha$, we can write the theory of $L_\alpha$. There are uncountably many such theories in $L$ because every countable ordinal $\beta$ is definable without parameters in some such $L_\alpha$, and so the digits of the $L$-least real coding $\beta$ is part of that theory. So some such real is writable from a countable $\alpha$ but not from $\omega_1$.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is positive in the sense that even with parameter $\omega_1$ it wouldn't be possible to (eventually) write the code (well-order relation on $\mathbb{N}$)  of some ordinal $\beta<\omega^L_1$. However, given any arbitrary ordinal $\alpha<\omega^L_1$, one can always (eventually) write the code for $\alpha$. So we can just take the code of $\beta$ as the real $x$ required in the question.

Comment: Is the answer also "Yes" if "eventually writable" is replaced with "antirecognizable"? Is the set of reals _antirecognizable_ in the parameter $\omega_1$ countable in $L$?

Comment: If antirecognizable means that there is an algorithm that says no to everything except the given real, then this follows from the fact that there are only countably many programs.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I was implying the notion of being “antirecognizable” as described in Lemma 2.3 in the linked paper or in Definition 4.5.1 in the book “Ordinal Computability” [Merlin Carl]. As far as I understand, a real $x$ is “antirecognizable” if and only if there is a program $P$ such that, for all $y \subseteq \omega$, an OTM-program $P$ diverges (i.e. does not halt) if and only if the input $y$ is equal to $x$.

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent to what I said. And so there are only countably many (for any fixed input), because each program determines at most one such real.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the question was already answered before my comment. This is how I thought about it (perhaps this slow thinking might be helpful for other non-experts, though I am not quite certain about this).

**(1)** In general, first we can observe that, given an ordinal parameter $\alpha$, if an ordinal $x$ is eventually writeable then every ordinal less than $x$ is also eventually writeable.

**(2)** Now observe that for any arbitrary ordinal $\alpha<\omega^L_1$, given the parameter $\alpha$, the code of $\alpha$ is eventually writeable. By code of $\alpha$ I mean the well-order (on $\mathbb{N}$) with order-type $\alpha$.

**(3)** Finally observe that if a real number $r$ (seen as a subset of $\omega$) is eventually writeable using some ordinal parameter $\alpha$ then it is also "ordinal computable" using suitably large ordinal parameters. To be specific, suppose the program with index $e$ when given the parameter $\alpha$ permanently stabilizes its first $\omega$ cells to $r$ beyond some time $T$. Or to put it other way, $T$ is the stabilization time for the real $r$ given the ordinal parameter $\alpha$ and program $\phi_e$.

Now, alternatively, we can think of $r$ as being **computed** with ordinal parameters $\alpha$ and $T$. This re-phrasing can be relevant (and is relevant in the context of this question), due to equivalence of "ordinal computation with parameters" with "constructible subsets of ordinals".

---

Now the answer to the question is implicit in the above points. That is, suppose that using the parameter $\omega_1$ it was possible to eventually write the code for some ordinal $\geq \omega^L_1$. By point-(1) above, then using the parameter $\omega_1$ it would also be possible to eventually write the code for some ordinal $\omega^L_1$ itself. However, now by point-(3) that would imply that code of $\omega^L_1$ is constructible (which is clearly false).

Hence we conclude that our original assumption was incorrect and hence using the parameter $\omega_1$ it is impossible to eventually write the code for some ordinal $\geq \omega^L_1$. That means that there exists a countable ordinal $\beta<\omega^L_1$ whose code is not eventually writeable using the parameter $\omega_1$. But now, using point-(2), the code for $\beta$ is writeable using the ordinal parameter $\beta$.

Comment: "**(2)** Now observe that for any arbitrary ordinal $\alpha<\omega^L_1$, given the parameter $\alpha$, the code of $\alpha$ is eventually writeable." I guess instead of "*the* code of $\alpha$", it should be something like "*some* code for $\alpha$".